# Is there a better way to order levels and factors together? I have successfully ordered them but there must be a more elegant way.

Tags: r, factors

Create a month vector.

```
> mths<-month.abb
> mths
[1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
```

but this is character vector, hence I convert it to factors as follows:

```
> mths1<-factor(mths)
> mths1
[1] Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
Levels: Apr Aug Dec Feb Jan Jul Jun Mar May Nov Oct Sep
```

But now the order of levels is shown Alphabetic, Which is not what we want. Trying the following we get the levels in the correct order but data gets jumbled.

```
> levels(mths1)<-mths
> mths1
 [1] May Apr Aug Jan Sep Jul Jun Feb Dec Nov Oct Mar
Levels: Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
```

And then I tried this:

```
> mths1[]<-mths
> mths1
 [1] Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
Levels: Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
```

And now the factors as well as their levels are all sorted correctly.

I want to know what is the dynamics happening behind the scenes in each of the above cases as the assignments to levels and data got me a bit confused.

Finally, what is a more elegant way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: `mths1<-factor(mths,levels=mths)` (or more generally `factor(mths,levels=unique(mths))`

Comment: You should also make it an ordered factor.

Comment: @Roland: why bother? Ordering makes little difference unless you want to (1) apply comparison operators or (2) use the variable (with orthogonal polynomial contrasts) in a statistical model.

Comment: @BenBolker Or unless you want to use ggplot2. There is a number of reasons for creating a factor. For some of them an ordered factor is useful and for most of them it doesn't hurt. OP seems to care about the order so making an ordered factor seems appropriate.

Comment: does ggplot2 really need ordered factors? that would surprise me greatly. How does ggplot2 behave differently with ordered vs 'regular' factors?

Answer (score 2):

Combining comments above into an answer

```
mths<-month.abb
mths
# [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
mths1 <-factor(mths, levels=mths, ordered=TRUE) 
mths1
# [1] Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
# Levels: Jan < Feb < Mar < Apr < May < Jun < Jul < Aug < Sep < Oct < Nov < Dec
```